# can not download file in linux using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

```
<?php
// Make sure an ID was passed
include('include/function.php');
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Get the ID
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);

    // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
    if($id <= 0) {
        die('The ID is invalid!');
    }
    else {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jio', 'jio');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Fetch the file information
        $query = "
            SELECT `id`,`date`,`expected_date`,`comname`,`type`,`name`,`path`,`mime`, `size`, `data`,`other_detail`,`remark`,`username`
            FROM `depository`
            WHERE `id` = {$id}";
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        if($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                // Print headers

                header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
                header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']);


            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
            }

            // Free the mysqli resources
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
}
?>
```

I am trying to download file from path location(doc root) but getting a empty file download or corrupt file download. anyone can suggest me where i am wrong in above code or use anything else.

Comment: You are sending the headers, but where are you sending the actual contents of the file?

Comment: Print data
                echo $row['path'];

Comment: Check to there is no other output like warnings or chars that is sent to the output buffer before the file contents. That messes things up and makes the files corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sending the headers you need to read the file contents and send that data - the following isn't tested but is more or less what you need to do. You will probably need to adjust the `$filepath` variable according to the contents of `$row['path']` from the sql result.

```
if($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
    header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']);

    /* you need to actually read the file and send it */

    $filepath=$row['path'] . '/' . $row['name'];
    if( !realpath( $filepath ) ) exit('Filepath '.$filepath.' is incorrect');

    if( $file = fopen( $filepath, 'rb' ) ) {
        while( !feof( $file ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
            print( fread( $file, 1024*8 ) );
            flush();
        }
        fclose( $file );
    }

}
```